# Crash of Ubuntu 15.04 working in Libre office

Tags: libreoffice

Ubuntu 15.04 crashes or freezes when I select text by dragging with the mouse in LibreOffice Writer. It also occurs to me when I click the menu to select it.

The only solution is to turn the PC off and on via the power button because the cursor does nothing.

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** Sólo Inglés, por favor...

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.(but just until Ubuntu has a better update on drivers or something else). There it goes:

I just verified it on nvidia video cards.

Select the driver options. Then, select: [nvidia legacy binary driver - version 304.125 of nvidia-304-updates (proprietary)]

I don't know why this is the option which works, but it does.